# What do reset() and back() method do in Scene

Tags: android, andengine

I have a GameScene class which extends scene . Like

```
public class GameScene extends Scene {

    public GameScene() {

    }

    public void clearScene() {
        this.reset();
        this.back();
    }
}
```

I found somewhere reset() & back() method when transforming between scene to unload previous resources. But i don't know what they do??!!!

Somebody can explain what they do..

Comment: Keyword itself says, that `reset()` which resets completely scene so that the player can restart the game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `reset` method of `Entity` resets to default all members of the `Entity` class: Position, scaling, rotation, color, visibility, entity modifiers and children (And a few more).

The `reset` method of `Scene` calls the `Entity.reset` method, and clears the child scene if there's any.

The `back` method of `Scene` clears the *child scene* of the *parent scene*. This, effectively, quits the current scene if any other scene uses it as a child scene.

For example: If we have a parent scene and a child scene, after a call to `ParentScene.setChildScene(ChildScene)`:

[image: Child scene]

After the call to `ChildScene.back()`, our parent scene will have no child scene.

[image: No child scene anymore]

I hope this explains well :)

Comment: thanks @Jong. Now it's very clear to me. One thing, does it unload the child scene resources when i calling reset or back to set child scene null?

Comment: It only sets the child scene reference to null. It might not get GCed yet if you have any other references pointing to it (And, of course, it doesn't unload resources)